# Converter segundos em horas no ExtJS

Tags: extjs, conversão

Estou querendo converter segundos em horas no ExtJS e gostaria de saber se existe uma função similar à **gmdate("H:i:s", $total)** no PHP.

Comment: Qual formato você deseja?
Existe uma resposta para essa pergunta:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066447/how-to-display-time-and-date-in-extjs

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma função em javascript. Algo como:

```
function segundosParaHora(seg) {
        var horas = Math.floor(seg/(60*60));

        var resto = seg % (60*60);
        var minutos = Math.floor(seg/60);

        resto %= 60;
        segundos = Math.ceil(resto);

        var hora = {
            "H": horas,
            "i": minutos,
            "s": segundos
        };
        return hora;
}
```

Utilizei 60*60 por questões de legibilidade (60s em 1min e 60min em 1 hora), mas você pode colocar o 3600 sem problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tive dificuldades em encontrar uma função JS que realmente funcione.

Vou deixar aqui a que atendeu minhas necessidades:

```js
function segParaHora(time, with_seg = true){
    
  var hours = Math.floor( time / 3600 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (time % 3600) / 60 );
  var seconds = time % 60;
    
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;      
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
    
  if(with_seg){
     return  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }
    
  return  hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```